# proof that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+2n+1}$ diverges, by comparsion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I need to prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+2n+1}$$

diverges by comparsion.

The way I did was to use

$$\frac{n}{n^2+2n+1}>\frac{n}{n^2+2n^2+n^2} = \frac{n}{4n^2} = \frac{1}{4n}$$

which diverges. Can I do that? Because $$2n+1<2n^2+n^2\implies n^2+2n+1<n^2+2n^2+n^2\implies $$

$$\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}>\frac{1}{n^2+2n^2+n^2}$$

for large $n$.

I also tried seeing

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+2n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$$

but I couldn't find any comparsion for that. Am I right in the first demonstration? Can you find a comparsion for the second attempt I did?

Comment: Your first comparison is valid. For the second comparison, try some partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Can you explain why the first comparison failed? I think it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n}{n^2+2n+1} = \frac{n}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{n + 1 - 1}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

Which diverges because $\frac{1}{n+1}$ does so and $\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}$ doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your first demonstration is ok. For the second one, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+2n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$$

You can try [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{(1+n)^2}=1,$$ where $a_n=\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Since limit is $1$ and $\sum b_n$ is diverges so $\sum a_n$ also diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)^2} \geq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+n)^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4n^2} = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty. $$

Answer (score 1):

$n/(n^2+2 n+1)=1/(n+2 +1/n^2)\geq 1/(n+3)$, and $\sum_n 1/(n+3)$ diverges.